# MongoDb Projection in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

```
namespace mongodbconnect
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mongoDbClient = new MongoClient();
            var mydb = mongoDbClient.GetDatabase("mydb");
            var CBook = mydb.GetCollection<Book>("Book");    
            var x = CBook.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project(Builders<Book>.Projection.Include("name").Exclude("_id")).ToList();

            foreach(Book b in x)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(b._id);
                Console.WriteLine(b.name);
            }




            Console.WriteLine("End");
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
    }
}
```

foreach loop show me an error as cannot convert type MongoDb.Bson.BsonDocument to mongodbconnect.Book. What should i change?

Comment: you excluded _id and trying to print _id, just wondering. please post Book class and some data

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BsonSerializer` class to convert your `BsonDocument` which is a result of your custom projection into a `Book` class. Since your `_id` is an integer, in C# you'll get default value for int which is `0`

```
var CBook = mydb.GetCollection<Book>("book");
var x = CBook.Find<Book>(FilterDefinition<Book>.Empty)
             .Project(Builders<Book>.Projection.Exclude(book => book._id))
             .ToList()
             .Select(bson => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Book>(bson));
```

Comment: If if do that i get both _id and name of book class.

Book class definiton: 

  public class Book
    {
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @ManishaPalanisamy, true, apologies. Try my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Or you can convert Projection to Projection<T,T>

```
ProjectionDefinition<Book,Book> projection= Builders<Book>.Projection.Exclude(book => book._id);
var CBook = mydb.GetCollection<Book>("book");
var x = CBook.Find<Book>(FilterDefinition<Book>.Empty)
         .Project(projection)
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works

```
       var x = CBook.Find(new 
        BsonDocument()).Project(Builders<Book>.Projection
       .Include("name").Exclude("_id")).ToList();


        foreach (BsonDocument b in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Bookname>(b).name);

        }
```